# Leaflet / LayersControl / Custom buttons on mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, leaflet, touch-event

i am JS / jQuery beginner and maybe is stupid but i have problem with add + remove custom buttons to Leaflet LayersControl on mobile devices.

Description of project:
I have map with multiple layers and i need to add two buttos for check / uncheck all checkboxes (it works in example).

Here is my example and **is neccessary to turn on touch simulation in browser**:
https://jsfiddle.net/lukassliacky/n2ep6yg0/42/ (created and tested on Firefox).

As i said, i am JS still beginner and for me seems to be the most easiest solution adding custom HTML with `after` but i have problem with events on touch devices.

On desktop (non touch) it looks quite simple: in top right corner is icon for collapsed LayerControl and i am using events `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` for add and remove custom buttons. It looks fine and i think that is good and working solution (this case isn't included in my example)

And i have problem on mobile / touch devices because i don't know which events can i use for add + remove.

I think that for add event looks good e.g. `click`, `tap` or `touchstart` but i don't know how to remove buttons when LayerControl is expanded and it will be collapsed.
Its quiet complicated for me because i need to exlude some divs from map (LayerControl with checboxes - when i would to click on checboxes, my custom buttons will be removed)

```
  $('#main-map:not(leaflet-control-layers-expanded > div).click(function() {
    $('.leaflet-custom-buttons').remove()

  })
  $('.leaflet-control').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
```

When i have expanded LayersControl (with buttons) and when i click on Pin marker, buttons are removed and LayerControl is still expanded (it isn't good). In this case is LayersControl collaped after click on different object as Pin Marker.

Please, can you help me with using right events for add / remove custom buttons on mobile devices? Of course, maybe is my approach wrong and it will be necessary to rewrite my code.

Thank you

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want this LayersControl on mobile devices to behave in the same way as on desktop devices, i.e. to disappear.
I think you shouldn't change it, it's in line with UX rules and that's what it should do on mobile devices.

If you want to hide something on mobile devices, you can also use the following css entry:
```@media (hover: hover) { a: hover { background: yellow; } }```
Unfortunately, it doesn't work in IE, but who would care;)

Comment: Hi @GrzegorzT. thank you for your answer. My english isn't my native language and maybe i described my "problem" not enough. When i tap on LayersControl icon on mobile device i need to **open div with checkboxes and with my custom buttons** (this part works quiet good). And when i click outside of this LayersControl div i need same behavior for LayersControl div and custom buttons. Current state: When i click on map except Pin Markers, is works fine, but when i click directly on Pin Marker, LayersControl is still opened and my custom buttons are removed - i need same behavior. Thank you.

Comment: I tried the 2nd round of googling and i found probably better approach for custom buttons: https://embed.plnkr.co/Je7c0m/ I am trying to implement this example to my project and i will write here result.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, i tried different approach and seems to be a correct way.

Updated example with working custom buttons is here: https://jsfiddle.net/lukassliacky/n2ep6yg0/57/

```js
    var cities = L.layerGroup();
    var secondLayer = L.layerGroup();
    var thirdLayer = L.layerGroup();
  

    L.marker([39.61, -105.02]).bindPopup('This is Littleton, CO.').addTo(cities),
    L.marker([39.24, -104.39]).bindPopup('This is Denver, CO.').addTo(cities),
    L.marker([39.33, -103.2]).bindPopup('This is Aurora, CO.').addTo(cities),
    L.marker([39.17, -105.43]).bindPopup('This is Golden, CO.').addTo(cities);

    L.marker([39.51, -105.52]).bindPopup('This is Littleton, CO.').addTo(secondLayer),
    L.marker([39.34, -104.29]).bindPopup('This is Denver, CO.').addTo(secondLayer),
    L.marker([39.13, -104.3]).bindPopup('This is Aurora, CO.').addTo(secondLayer),
    L.marker([39.97, -105.63]).bindPopup('This is Golden, CO.').addTo(secondLayer);
  
  L.marker([39.21, -105.52]).bindPopup('This is Littleton, CO.').addTo(thirdLayer),
    L.marker([39.34, -104.09]).bindPopup('This is Denver, CO.').addTo(thirdLayer),
    L.marker([39.73, -104.28]).bindPopup('This is Aurora, CO.').addTo(thirdLayer),
    L.marker([39.17, -105.53]).bindPopup('This is Golden, CO.').addTo(thirdLayer);

    var mbAttr = 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        mbUrl = 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw';

    var grayscale   = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {id: 'mapbox/light-v9', tileSize: 512, zoomOffset: -1, attribution: mbAttr}),
        streets  = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {id: 'mapbox/streets-v11', tileSize: 512, zoomOffset: -1, attribution: mbAttr});

    var map = L.map('main-map', {
        center: [39.73, -104.99],
        zoom: 7,
        layers: [grayscale, cities, secondLayer, thirdLayer]
    });

    var baseLayers = {
/*      "Grayscale": grayscale,
        "Streets": streets */
    };

    var overlays = {
        "Cities": cities,
    "SecondLayer": secondLayer,
    "ThirdLayer": thirdLayer,
    
    };


L.Control.Custom = L.Control.Layers.extend({
    onAdd: function () {
            this._initLayout();
            this._addCheckButton();
            this._addClearButton();
            this._update();
            return this._container;
        },
        _addCheckButton: function () {
        var elements = this._container.getElementsByClassName('leaflet-control-layers-list');
        var button = L.DomUtil.create('button', 'btn btn-primary rounded-0 my-1 me-1 btn-xs leaflet-btn-check-all', elements[0]);
        button.textContent = 'Check All';
        L.DomEvent.on(button, 'click', function(e){
            L.DomEvent.stop(e);

            // fire this function (check all)
            $('.leaflet-control input[type="checkbox"]').trigger('click').prop('checked', true);
        }, this);
        },
        _addClearButton: function () {
        var elements = this._container.getElementsByClassName('leaflet-control-layers-list');
        var button = L.DomUtil.create('button', 'btn btn-primary rounded-0 my-1 btn-xs w-50 leaflet-btn-check-all', elements[0]);
        button.textContent = 'Clear All';
        L.DomEvent.on(button, 'click', function(e){
            L.DomEvent.stop(e);

            // fire this function (uncheck all)
            $('.leaflet-control input[type="checkbox"]').trigger('click').prop('checked', false);
        }, this);
        }
    });
    
    new L.Control.Custom(
        baseLayers, 
        overlays,
        {collapsed:true}).addTo(map);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet-locatecontrol/0.74.0/L.Control.Locate.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }
        #main-map   {
            width: 100%;
            height: 500px;
        }
    </style>    
</head>
<body>

<div id='main-map'></div>
```

My solution is based on https://embed.plnkr.co/Je7c0m/ and i am really thank to author.
Grzegorz T. thank you for your support too.